# How to define the base url for the asp.net core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, base-url

I have one ASP.NET Core 3.1.0 web app and I am struggling to understand the url exposed by asp.net core.

I have one single controller

```
[Route("accounts")]
public class AccountsController : BaseController
{
    public AccountsController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("{test}")]
    public string DefaultMethod()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs, I am using UsePathBase as

```
app.UsePathBase("/account-api");
```

When I start the app, I can access the method as

http://localhost:5000/account-api/accounts/test and it is fine

But I can also access it via http://localhost:5000/accounts/test which I want to restrict.

How can I restrict this?

Comment: You may want to decorate your controller with ```[Route("account-api/[controller]")]``` to restrict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```cs
         app.UseMvc(routes =>
         {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "account-api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
         });
```

Comment: I am using Web API template and without MVC so don't think this should be used in my case

Comment: why not? it's completely fine to use MVC model in  WebAPIs. but you have `app.UseRouter` option too. instead of useMvc. @BhavikSuthar

Comment: I have marked this as answered but went with app.UseRouter as UseMVC gave the wrong impression on the codebase